# iPad Mini internet connection (No WiFi)

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

I'm planning to buy an iPad mini + cellular but not on my country. I would buy itt on the United States and someone is going to bring it to me. I have some questions:

- The person who is going to buy the ipad Mini would need to choose a data service from AT&T or any of the other services?
- If it is necessary and the person picks AT&T... would i need to unblock it or something like that? The person would need to suscribe to some kind of data plan?
- In my country there isn't LTE cellular network yet... The 3G will work?

Comment: Be very careful.  There is no guarantee that US phones work in another country.

Answer (score 1):

In the US - all iPads (including the mini) are unlocked, pay as you please, no contract devices. The two models of mini are A1454 and A1455 with similar GSM 3G coverage:

- Model A1454

  - GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
  - UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz)
  - LTE (Bands 4 and 17)
- Model A1455

  - CDMA EV-DO Rev. A and Rev. B (800, 1900, 2100 MHz)
  - GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
  - UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1900, 2100 MHz)
  - LTE (Bands 1, 3, 5, 13, 25)

http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/

Accordingly, you can pick whether want to optimize your LTE future bands (or travel bands) or choose a CDMA+GSM model or the GSM only model. Since there are very few countries with CDMA coverage out side the USA, most people end up shopping the AT&T model 1454 - but curiously, the CDMA model 1455 matches many foreign LTE deployments and plans, so it's a bit of a tradeoff which any one person might prefer world wide.